# How to return two different values in Python based on the time of execution?

Tags: python, time

I am new in coding. I am writing this code in Python 3. There is a function called `function()`. If you call this function for the first time, it returns `result1`. When you call this function again, if the time of call is less than 1 minutes from the previous call, it returns `result2`, otherwise it again returns the `result1`, and resets the time, so this logic can go on forever. How is that possible?

Update: I don't even know how to begin. This is basically what I've done so far:

```
first_call = datetime.datetime.now()
second_call = 0
show_new_resut = False
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon and Tobin Please see the update. I don't even know how to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some variable outside of the function to store a global state.  One example of how this could work is:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

last_called : datetime = None
def foo() -> str:
    global last_called 
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    if last_called == None or now - last_called > timedelta(minutes=1):
        result = "result1"
    else:
        result = "result2"

    last_called = now 
    return result
```

Here, we're caching the current time in the module-level variable `last_called` every time the function is executed, and changing the result based on whether that value is within one minute of the current time.  If this were a method in a class, you could use a class attribute/field, rather than a global, which would be better practice and a bit tidier.

Comment: I appreciate it very much. As I said, I am very new. Don't know what -> means. Can you make it a bit easier for me?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit of a habit from other development I'm doing; the `: datetime` and `-> str` are [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), a way of denoting what type you expect a variable to have. They are an optional language feature, but recommended for large projects (especially with multiple developers).  If you aren't using type hints, then you can remove them (e.g. the lines become `last_called = None` and `def foo():`)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In this example, `returnval1` stores `result1`, and `returnval2` stores `result2`.

```
import time
def function(lastcall=0):
    result1 = "hi!"
    result2 = "hello!"
    currenttime = time.time()
    if currenttime - lastcall < 60:
        return result2, currenttime
    else:
        return result1, currenttime

returnval1, lastcall = function()
returnval2, lastcall = function(lastcall)
print(returnval1, returnval2)
```